# How to edit and save my html file using Quill?

Tags: quill

So I have a text file on my web server, which i display using  tag in browser.

I need to edit the file every once in a while, as of now i have to go back to CLI and vi the file.

I want to use some WYSISYG editor to do it online. I was considering CKEditor, but found Quill too. Quill looked lige to me.

I am confused how can I use it to edit the displayed text file in browser and then save the contents back to the text file in server. I also want to format the text in file using WYSISWYG editor (like highlighting, bold, insert pictures etc.).

I want to save a text and HTML version of file in the server, just in case web-server/web-site is not functioning, I would still be able to use data thru CLI. I felt i need to store output of this tool in db in the backend??

any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a simple matter to do with Quill, because Quill is able to "translate" quite fairly well (not always the case though..) html markup into its `Delta` format. Then Quill only manipulate and saves/render `Delta` format operations/snapshots.

In our case, we store that specific format (which is great btw, atomic, concise, lightweight,..) server-side and always render it through Quill (on edit mode or read-only mode).

If you absolutely want to store an html version of it and not really concerned by security (XSS injection and stuff, if you are in a admin only section, dunno) maybe send directly your DOM html content inside Quill editor node, but I'd rather avoid that though.

Comment: maybe i can use some jquery library to save displayed HTML file as text on server.  but I am totally unable to understand how does it save the data on server? Is it in MySQL? Do you have any sample to share which show the data saved on server side? Does it save all edits like a versioning system?

Comment: I actually prefer to keep all data in sql tables and want to have ability to display all of that as one page. so that i can edit individual words/elements and update the backend. I can do this with jquery+mysql+xeditable. But it does not have the ability to highlight or color field, or upload and display images etc...

Comment: Use anytime `var content = quill.getContents()` to have the javascript object representing your html content. You always could stringify that to send it to any backend API you want `JSON.stringify(content)` and store it  in mysql, redis, mongo, etc.. We do that in Redis and Postgre in our case. Then to load this backend content, just call `quill.setContents(contentsFromBackend)` and voila.

Comment: on the quill website, can you please put an example: where a portion of webpage only is edited by clicking and edit button (thus editing a portion using quill) and then saving the 'change/new text' back to backend. I would say a demo list of name and sales_numbers will be good enough.